# Leaflet Routing Machine: how to export route details and coordinates in JSON / GeoJSON?

Tags: json, routes, leaflet, geojson

I need to export / save the route details found using Leaflet Routing Machine in JSON or GeoJSON format.

I've tried to  use

```
var routeArray = new Array();
routeArray = control.getWaypoints();
alert (JSON.stringify(routeArray));
```

that works but in this manner I obtain only the waypoints and, instead,  I'm interested at ALL the route details (coordinates  and descriptions).

I guess that "somewhere" they are (in the picture when I put my mouse pointer on a description I can see a little blue circle on the map as you can see .... )

[image]

Any suggestion, example, jsfiddle to help me? Thank you very much in advance!!!

Cesare

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle `routeselected` event from your `L.Routing.control` object:

```
routingCtrl.on('routeselected', function(routes) {
    console.log(routes);
    console.log(routes.route.instructions);
}, this);
```

The `routes` variable contains all the information lealfet machine uses to build what you see on the screen. Check specifically `routes.route.instructions` and `routes.route.coordinates` objects